# use universality property to prove the existence of isomorphism

Tags: tensor-products

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $K$. Use the universality property of tensor products to show that there exists a canonical isomorphism $f:V^{*}\otimes W\to Hom_K(V,W)$.

I know that to universality property I have to define something like $\phi:V^{*}\times W\to Hom_K(V,W)$ given by $$[\phi(l,w)](v):=l(v)w$$. But I think my problem is that, I don't know how to clearly state the universality property and use the above $\phi$ to prove the final result. Thank you very much!

Comment: Universality guarantees that to any bilinear map $b:V^* \times W \rightarrow X$ ($X$ a $K$ vector space) there exists a map $\beta :V^*\otimes W \rightarrow X$ such that $\beta\circ \iota=b$, where $\iota: V^*\times W \rightarrow V^*\otimes W$ maps $(v^*, w)$ to $v^*\otimes w $. Now let $X=Hom_K(V,W)$.

Comment: @Thomas Make that an answer?

Comment: @OscarCunningham this was just meant as a starting point, since the OP wrote that this is where he is stuck. There is still work ahead (I did not check nor did I claim that he used a suitable $\Phi$. I also said nothing about 'canonical', and it remains to show that you get an isomorphism).